# How can we use getCountryTranslation() in magento2

Tags: magento2

I need full country name using short code.
I have code for magento 1.9 But I need it for magento2. can any one help me please.

```
$customerBillingCountry = 'IE'; 

$customerBillingCountry = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getCountryTranslation($customerBillingCountry);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
$customerBillingCountry =   $objectManager->create('\Magento\Directory\Model\Country')->load($customerBillingCountry)->getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to get the full name of the country from country code

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory
) 
{
        $this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;
}

public function getCountryname($countryCode){    
    $country = $this->_countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($countryCode)
    return $country->getName();
}
```

call in your template file

```
echo $block->getCountryname($countryCode);
```

Comment: I have used it on outside of magento and this was worked perfect. $customerBillingCountry =   $objectManager->create('\Magento\Directory\Model\Country')->load($customerBillingCountry)->getName();

Comment: Ok. it's another solution using block method.